# Does there exist a pdf-viewer for ubuntu offering up to 6400 percent zoom?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

The question is in the title.

I can hardly believe it, but after having tried each of 'evince', 'Master PDF', 'okular', 'xpdf', I am quite sure that none of these well-known readers offers as high a zoom factor as does e.g. Acroreader. For my work it is *indispensable* to have at least 6400% zoom, and, having recently changed to ubuntu, I now seem to find myself in a situation in which the only way is to try to get Acroreader running via Wine (which I didn't try yet, and hope to be able to avoid trying).

Answer (score 7):

You can have Evince zoom at higher levels by increasing the page cache size. For example,

`gsettings set org.gnome.Evince page-cache-size 500`

will increase the page-cache size from 50 MiB, the default, to 500 MiB, and thus increase the available zoom to 1600%. You can try with higher values. However, from certain zoom levels onwards, it won't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can try to install QPDFView with `sudo apt-get install qpdfview`. It allows high zoom levels as 5000%.
2. As far I know old unsupported Adobe Reader 9 for linux allows 6400% zoom.

   You can install it manually from 12.04 LTS repository and other packages.
   Usually it is bad idea. But if you really needed it, you can proceed with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
   wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/139930013/acroread-bin_9.5.5-1precise1_i386.deb
   wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/139930012/acroread_9.5.5-1precise1_i386.deb
   wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/n/nspluginwrapper/nspluginviewer_1.4.4-0ubuntu5_i386.deb
   wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/n/nspluginwrapper/nspluginwrapper_1.4.4-0ubuntu5_i386.deb
   sudo gdebi -n nspluginviewer_1.4.4-0ubuntu5_i386.deb
   sudo gdebi -n nspluginwrapper_1.4.4-0ubuntu5_i386.deb
   sudo gdebi -n acroread-bin_9.5.5-1precise1_i386.deb
   sudo gdebi -n acroread_9.5.5-1precise1_i386.deb
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```

Comment: Thanks. This helps me, to some extent. For what's it's worth, it may be helpful to someone else to note that (0) I installed and tested QPDFView on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and it worked, (1) one can get *higher* zoom than what the pulldown-menu offers, by pressing 'Crtl+ArrowUp', (2) on my system at least, 5000% are *not* achieved, and, curiously, it seems to depend on the pdf-file which zoom is possible: on one file, I get to 1141%, and from then on, it doesn't load anymore (despite my waiting long), on another file, I get to 2446%. Thanks again, and I would appreciate to hear of alternatives.

Comment: As I can understand maximum zoom in QPDFView is limited by available RAM.

Answer (score 0):

In [*Foxit Reader*](https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-foxit-reader-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04-desktop/), the magnification goes up to 6400% (as of Version 2.4.1.0609, at least).

[image]